# Nginx and two Django projects

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I want to setup two different Django projects in my VPS - there are two different Gunicorn instances (two different virutalenvs). The first project works perfectly:

Nginx for first project:

```
server {
server_name 95.85.34.87;

access_log off;
    sendfile off;

location /static/ {
    root Lynx/lynx/lynx_static_files/;
}

location / {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET,POST,OPTIONS";
    add_header         Access-Control-Allow-Headers   Content-Type;
    add_header         Access-Control-Max-Age         86400;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
}
}
```

Gunicorn for first project:

```
gunicorn_django --bind localhost:8001
```

Nginx for second project:

```
server {
server_name 95.85.34.87:8002;

access_log off;
    sendfile off;

location /static/ {
    root Komodo/komodo/komodo_static_files/;
}

location / {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET,POST,OPTIONS";
    add_header         Access-Control-Allow-Headers   Content-Type;
    add_header         Access-Control-Max-Age         86400;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8002;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
}
}
```

Gunicorn for second project:

```
gunicorn_django --bind 95.85.34.87:8002
```

**Problem**:  `95.85.34.87` shows my first project with static files (everything works fine), `95.85.34.87:8002` also works (Gunicorn is working), but unfortunately Nginx doesn't serve static files for this second project for some reason. I think the reason behind the problem is `server_name` setting, but i  am not sure how to set it up to show my statics for second project.

Comment: Are there any errors? Does nginx have permissions for the 2nd projects static files?

Comment: Hi. Nope, the var/log/nginx/error.log file shows no errors. The static files are simply not showing, I am just getting a 404 error while trying to directly access a .js file. And how should I check if nginx have permissions ?

Comment: 404's show up in `access.log`, and so do 403's, which is what you'd get if nginx didn't have permissions for those files. Why don't you see what errors your browsers inspector gives for those files when you  browse to your site?

Comment: For some reason the access.log file is not present, but error.log showed me, that `2014/05/04 08:06:22 [emerg] 28989#0: bind() to 95.85.34.87:8002 failed (98: Address already in use)`. I think that nginx can not listen to `95.85.34.87:8002`, because gunicorn is listening to `95.85.34.87:8002`, ummm can this be true ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed my problem. I have just binded my second Project's Gunicicorn instance not to `95.85.34.87`, but to `localhost:8002` (same as project 1, but different port).